# How to dynamically define the Class that can be used as a parameter in a method?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a method that I use to validate a POJO in Spring MVC (this allows me to rely on the `@Annotation` in the POJO and at the same time validate the POJO programmatically whenever and wherever I want without using the annotation `@Valid`).

In need to pass the Class of the object to the method in order to validate:

```
public void validate(Class clazz, Object model, BindingResult result){      
    ...         
    Set<ConstraintViolation<clazz>> constraintViolations=validator.validate((clazz)model);
        for (ConstraintViolation<clazz> constraintViolation : constraintViolations) {
...
}
```

My code is not correct, since a get the error:

> clazz cannot be resolved to a type

How should I edit my code in order to be able to pass to this method any Class I want?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give a little more context & what the use-case for calling methods like `setList(Man)` is? Most of the time people try that's it's not actually needed because you can't use a "dynamic" type in your code. Because dynamic is at runtime and you'll have to write code & types before that.

Comment: I edited my post. I talked about a List to make my issue simper to be understood. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can  `generify` the method

```
public <T> void setList(Class<T> clazz){
  List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and call it as follows

```
setList(Person.class)
```

Comment: This would give you a polymorphic List, but it's not easy to include this method in a working generic class. Could you provide a small class example with a variable type List as property, where this method takes an argument as above?

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn "working generic class" is a term that I don't understand

Comment: If you try to include this method in a Class with a List<T> property, with useful methods, you will run into problems that can be worked around in different ways. This doesn't play all that well with static typing. You should, I think, include an actual example; so that the answer does not hide the actual complexity

Comment: I edited my post. I talked about a List to make my issue simper to be understood.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi I edited my method according to what you wrote and it works. I've never studied yet that sintax. What does it means <T> in a method signature? That it can return any type of data? Why should I put <T> inside the signature, since my problem is not the return type, but how to pass any type to the method?

Thank you

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali Search for "generics" and you should be able to understand them easily

Answer (score 2):

You should use generic:

```
public <T> void setList(){
   List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
...
obj.<Man>setList();
obj.<Woman>setList();
obj.<Person>setList();
```

or

```
    public <T> void setList(Class<T> clazz){
      List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
...
    obj.setList(Woman.class);
    obj.setList(Man.class);
    obj.setList(Person.class);
```

or

```
public static class MyClass <T> {
    public <T> void setList() {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}  
...
new MyClass<Woman>().setList();
new MyClass<Man>().setList();
new MyClass<Person>().setList();
```

**Update:**
Instead of code

```
public void validate(Class clazz, Object model, BindingResult result){      
    ...         
    Set<ConstraintViolation<clazz>> constraintViolations=validator.validate((clazz)model);
        for (ConstraintViolation<clazz> constraintViolation : constraintViolations) {
...
}
```

use code

```
public void <T> validate(Class<T> clazz, Object<T> model, BindingResult result){      
    ...         
    Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> constraintViolations=validator.validate(model);
        for (ConstraintViolation<T> constraintViolation : constraintViolations) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you man, it  works.
I've never studied yet that sintax. What does it means <T> in a method signature? I suppose is means that the method can return any type of data!? Why should I put <T> inside the signature? My problem is not the return type, but how to pass any type to the method? Thank you for the explanation

Comment: You imagine that for every type instead of <T> Java generate 3 method for Man, Women and Person and replace <T> to Man, Women and Person type in code. It's more easy to undestand what is <T> means.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you don't need a type and can use an unbound wildcard:

```
public void validate(Class<?> clazz, Object model, BindingResult result){      
    ...         
    Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> constraintViolations=validator.validate(model);
        for (ConstraintViolation<?> constraintViolation : constraintViolations) {
...
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html